# Hide dropdown duplicates when originally hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dropdown

I am successfully using the blow code to remove duplicate values from a drop down field

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 var usedNames = {};
 $("select > option").each(function () {
    if (usedNames[this.value]) {
        $(this).remove();
    } else {
        usedNames[this.value] = this.text;
    }
  });
   });
```

My problem is that some of my drop downs are conditional, so they are not on the page when the code fires, they are set to display:hidden, and input hidden, then depending on a previous drop down selcect they are shown.

So how can I fire the code when the drop down appears??

Comment: Could you not have it run this script wherever it is that the drop downs are being set to show?

Comment: Yes, thats what I want, but I dont know how to do it?

Comment: Show the code that is showing the drop downs.

Comment: its just straight forward but set to display:hidden, until the previous dropdown is selected. Its being created dynamically so I dont have the code that changes it to display:block

Answer (score 1):

If you have no ability to add code where the dropdown is being set to visible, your only solution may be to set a repeating timer to constantly check.

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){

    // Check to see if the thing is still hidden
    if(!$("#id_of_option").is(':hidden')){

        clearInterval(interval); // stop checking

        // Run your other code here to clear out duplicates

    }

}, 200); // or some number of milliseconds
```

Comment: actually I am able to add code inside the drop down it self

Comment: The code that is setting it to display? Then you should add in the code you have written above at that point.